# Group a range of integers such as no pair of numbers is shared by two or more groups

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

You are given two numbers, N and G. Your goal is to split a range of integers `[1..N]` in equal groups of G numbers each. Each *pair* of numbers must be placed in exactly one group. Order does not matter.

For example, given N=9 and G=3, I could get these 12 groups:

```
1-2-3
1-4-5
1-6-7
1-8-9
2-4-6
2-5-8
2-7-9
3-4-9
3-5-7
3-6-8
4-7-8
5-6-9
```

As you can see, each possible pair of numbers from 1 to 9 is found in exactly one group. I should also mention that such grouping cannot be done for every possible combination of N and G.

I believe that this problem can be modelled best with hypergraphs: numbers are vertexes, hyperedges are groups, each hyperedge must connect exactly $G$ vertexes and no pair of vertexes can be shared by any two hyperedges.

At first, I've tried to bruteforce this problem - recursively pick valid vertexes until either running out of vertexes or finding a solution. It was way too slow, so I've started to look for ways to cut off some definitely wrong groups. If a lesser set of groups was found to be invalid, then we can predict any other set of groups which includes that one to be invalid too.

Here is the code I have so far (I hope that lack of comments is not a big concern):

```python3
#!/usr/bin/python3
# Input format:
#  vertexes group_size
# Example:
#  9 3
from collections import deque
import itertools

def log(frmt, *args, **kwargs):
    'Lovely logging subroutine'
    if len(args)==len(kwargs)==0:
        print(frmt, file=stderr)
    else:
        print(frmt.format(*args, **kwargs), file=stderr)

v, g = map(int, input().split())
linkcount = (v*(v-1)) // 2
if (linkcount % g) != 0:
    print("INVALID GROUP SIZE")
    exit
groupcount = linkcount // g

def pairs(it):
    return itertools.combinations(it, 2)

# --- Vertex connections routines ---

connections = [[False for dst in range(v)] for src in range(v)] 
#TODO: optimize matrix to eat up less space for large graphs
#...that is, when the freaking SLOWNESS is fixed for graph size to make any difference. >_<
def connected(a, b):
    if a==b:
        return True
    if a>b:
        a, b = b, a
    # assert a<b
    return connections[a][b]
def setconnect(a, b, value):
    if a==b:
        return False
    if a>b:
        a, b = b, a
    # assert a<b
    connections[a][b] = value
def connect(*vs):
    for v1, v2 in pairs(vs):
        setconnect(v1, v2, True)
def disconnect(*vs):
    for v1, v2 in pairs(vs):
        setconnect(v1, v2, False)

# --
# --- Failure prediction routines ---
failgroups = {}

def addFailure(groupId):
    'Mark current group set as unsuccessful'
    cnode = failgroups
    sgroups = sorted(groups[:groupId+1])
    for gp in groups:
        if gp not in cnode:
            cnode[gp]={}
        cnode=cnode[gp]
    cnode['!'] = True # Aka "end of node"

def findInSubtree(node, string, stringptr):
    if stringptr>=len(string):
        return False
    c = string[stringptr]
    if c in node:
        if '!' in node[c]:
            return True
        else:
            return findInSubtree(node[c], string, stringptr+1)
    else:
        return findInSubtree(node, string, stringptr+1)


def predictFailure(groupId) -> bool:
    'Predict if the current group set will be unsuccessful'
    sgroups = sorted(groups[:groupId+1])
    return findInSubtree(failgroups, sgroups, 0)
# --
groups = [None for grp in range(groupcount)]

def debug_format_groups():
    return ' '.join(('-'.join((str(i+1)) for i in group) if group else '?') for group in groups) # fluffy formatting for debugging

def try_group(groupId):
    for cg in itertools.combinations(range(v), g):
        groups[groupId]=cg

        # Predict whether or not this group will be unsuccessful
        if predictFailure(groupId):
            continue
        # Verify that all vertexes are unconnected
        if any(connected(v1,v2) for v1,v2 in pairs(cg)):
            continue


        # Connect all vertexes
        connect(*cg)
        if groupId==groupcount-1:
            return True # Last group is successful! Yupee!
        elif try_group(groupId+1):
                # Next group was successful, so -
                return True
        # Disconnect these vertexes
        disconnect(*cg)
        # Mark this group set as unsuccessful
        addFailure(groupId)
    else:
        groups[groupId]=None
        return False

result = try_group(0)
if result:
    formatted_groups = sorted(['-'.join(str(i+1) for i in group) for group in groups])
    for f in formatted_groups:
        print(f)
else:
    print("NO SOLUTION")
```

Is this an NP-complete problem? Can it be generalized as another, well-known problem, and if so - as which?

P.S. That's not a homework or contest task, if anything.

P.P.S. Sorry for my bad English, it's not my native language. I have no objections if someone edited my question for more clear phrasing. Thanks! ^^

In the meantime, I'm ready to clarify all confusing moments here.

UPDATE:

I've been thinking about it and realized than there is a better way than backtracking. First, we could build a graph where vertices represent all possible *groups* and edges connect all groups without common pairs of numbers. Then, each clique of power (N(N-1)/2G) would represent a solution! Unfortunately, clique problem is an NP-complete task, and generating all possible binom(N, G) groups would eat up much memory on large values of N and G. Is it possible to find a better solution?

Comment: This is a combinatorics problem. You have \binom{N}{2} unordered couples and since in each group you can put G couples you need \binom{N}{2}/G groups. You need to calculate the odd situations with at least/at most, etc...

Comment: sorry there's an error in each group you can put \binom{G}{2} couples so you need \frac{\binom{N}{2}}{\binom{G}{2}} which is equal to \frac{N\*N-1}{G\*G-1}. In your example 9\*8 =72 divided by 3\*2=6 equals 12 (the formulas are in LaTex paste them here https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php)

Comment: @Alberto, I'm not very familiar with combinatorics. Could you rephrase this in more simple terms, please?

Comment: Combinatorics helps you on counting the number of groups you need, but I think it's not too difficult to develop an algorithm that lists your groups. Many math programs like R can do this but are not so straightforward to use.

Comment: @AlbertoRivelli, well... *Counting* the number of groups is probably the easiest part; in fact, you can see in my code it's already done (`groupcount` and `linkcount` definitions). It's *finding* these groups that I find difficult.

Comment: if you ask this question on mathoverflow you'd get the right answer after a few seconds :)

Comment: @AlbertoRivelli, I've [followed your advice](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1979205/group-a-range-of-integers-such-as-no-pair-of-numbers-is-shared-by-two-or-more-gr). Although, to be honest, I doubt it is a mathematical question: mathematics is all about theory. It is very useful when you need to calculate some obscure values, or prove a theorem, or something like that. Problems about *polynomial algorithms*, as far as I understand, are better classified as problems about programming. :)

Comment: I told you...http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1979205/group-a-range-of-integers-such-as-no-pair-of-numbers-is-shared-by-two-or-more-gr#comment4063300_1979205
Actually I suggested mathoverflow.net

Comment: @AlbertoRivelli, what do you mean by "I told you..."?

Comment: I told you'd get better answers and more interest there...

Comment: @AlbertoRivelli, you are right about "interest" part. It definitely attracted more attention, and I've got some very useful insight there. However, sadly, there are no "better answers" - they hardly help to solve the problem. Like I've stated in the above comment, mathematics is of little help when it comes to creating an efficient algorithm. I'm not saying it's not useful in algorithmics, far from it! Mathematics is essencial for solving many difficult programming problems and really helps to design algorithms. However, it just so happens that right now it comes down to efficiency.

Comment: I don't think so. You wrote an algorithm and you don't even know if it is correct, so you need the theory to prove your algorithm is correct. To do this you first need to model your problem. Then you can design an algorithm and eventually improve its speed. Are you sure 100% your algorithm produces always the correct result? Do you have a rigorous proof? I highly doubt that. They solved the hard part, modelling your problem. Designing an algorithm is relatively simple (and left to you) as the answer says. Then you can start improving the algorithm if possible with the known techniques.

Comment: @AlbertoRivelli, please, don't assume that. I **know** it is correct. I've already modelled the problem with graphs and my code already gives correct solutions. The problem is, it gives correct solutions very slowly, very inefficiently. What I'm looking for is either a drastic improvement to the existing algorithm, or - even better - a different model. Anything, what would allow to find solutions in polynomial time. (It goes without saying that I'm only reaching for an advice, in case it looks like I'm only demanding explanations without doing anything myself or something like that. >.<)

Comment: ok, I didn't understand when I first red your question that you already modelled it as a graph problem. In this case you can use a two-way reduction to an NP problem to prove you can't do better than that unless NP=P. Given that you've already shown that every instance of your problem is an instance of the k-clique problem, you only need to prove the other way (the hard one). I did understand you only wanted an algorithm for it no matter the running time. Regards.

Comment: Look at this answer I gave here, I think it's the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40193648/algorithm-to-group-items-in-groups-of-3 In your case it's much easier because your starting graph is always a complete graph! I'll look for the standard algorithm for this problem in this case.

Comment: @AlbertoRivelli, thanks! It is similar indeed. However, I think this problem may be actually harder than that one, because, as far as I know, algorithms for finding a maximum clique work better for sparse graphs. Clique Cover algorithms, however, may be entirely different matter, but I'm yet to find one.